# Set up route setting for variables after "?"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Could not figure out how to set up route for 
https://localhost/firstmvc/Account/LoginCallBack?error=access_denied 
in AccountController.cs

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Account/LoginCallBack/{error?}")]                
    public ActionResult LoginCallback(string error)
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("Error");
    }
```

This seems only work for https://localhost/firstmvc/Account/LoginCallBack/access_denied

Comment: Just make it `[Route("Account/LoginCallBack")]`

Answer (score 2):

Use the route to describe the path that you want, and the DefaultModelBinder will automatically pull method parameters from the querystring for you.

```
 [Route("Account/LoginCallBack")]                
 public ActionResult LoginCallback(string error)
 {
     return RedirectToRoute("Error");
  }
```